# How to Change Delay Time to Show Taskbar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, delay

I like to keep my Taskbar collapsed on my laptop for longer time.

Sometimes i need a control at the very bottom of my current program, so I am constantly accidentally expanding the taskbar.

What I'd like is to increase the delay time between when the cursor nears the taskbar and when it expands.

I do not want to change the delay of Thumbnail Previews but only the main taskbar!

Comment: That is not natively possible and I do not see a third party app (like tweakui) that would do that.

Comment: I found this - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8657f4f5-a9cd-4a32-ae2e-69927a8f6ac6/add-delay-time-to-the-taskbar-autoshowing-when-set-to-autohide?forum=win10itprogeneral Can't test, no Win machine here right now.